# Reduce bottom padding on header section

Tags: html, css

I have a weird issue going on that I can't figure out. I am working on the website invisionbilling.com. There is too much padding on the bottom of my header in Chrome (the part that contains `email`, `phone`, and `social media`).

It looks fine in Firefox and Internet Explorer, so it appears to be an issue only in Google Chrome. I've inspected elements and made adjustments but nothing seems to be working. I believe the div class `"header_top_sbb"` or `"col-md-4"` is what is affecting it but I could be wrong.

I am not able to provide HTML or CSS because I don't know what is causing the issue. Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: in the future you should include more information including screenshots code snippets or even fiddles. The more information you provide and the clearer you are the more likely people are going to answer your queston

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep all that in mind going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add to your own `style.css` file a rule like this one *(in order to overwrite the bootstrap's rule in kinda conflict)*, it'll fix that weird "padding":

```
@media (min-width: 992px) { .col-md-4 { font-size: 11px; } } // or < 14px, as you wish
```

Comment: Thanks Emerson! I actually went into the text widget and changed the font size and that worked. You were definitely on the right track with the font size. I never even considered that.